# Request object validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation

Can you explain how create validation for big nested request object, do you create validation by your self for every field in object for example:

```
if (name === undefined){
  errors = { name: 'name is required' }
} else if (typeof name !== 'String') {
  errors = { name: 'name must be a string' }
} else if (name.length < 2) {
  errors = { name: 'name length must be more 2' }
} else if ...
```

And so for each field, or use some libraries ?

Comment: you can use jquery validation plugins 
https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Joi library for request object validation.
Eg. to validate string in request object:

```
{
 name: Joi.string.required().description('user name')
}
```

Eg.to validate object

```
{
   userData: Joi.object({
     name: Joi.string.required().description('user name')
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [safen](https://github.com/corgidisco/safen) library for complex object validation.

**example**

```
const safen = require("safen")

const validation = safen.create({
  name: "string & length_min: 2",
})

validation.assert({name: "foo"}) // safe

validation.assert({name: 30}) // exception
validation.assert({name: "f"}) // exception
```